# Proving a square number

Tags: combinatorics

**a)** 
 Decide (without the help of a calculator) which of the following numbers
$t = 1 125$, $u = 1 225$, $v = 111 225$ and $w = 112 225$ square numbers.
If necessary, specify the numbers whose squares are present.

**b)**
The whole number[image] consists of $4038$ digits (in the usual tens system), namely $2018$ ones, $2019$ twos, and a five.
Show that the number a is a square number, and specify the number representation of the number $b$ with $$b ^ 2 = a$$

Comment: What have you tried ? For example you can probably find the number of digits in the number b of question 2, then give relation for those digits, etc ...

Comment: I tried with 333...35 formula but looks like I can't find a solution

Comment: (a) I'd multiply them by $4$.

Comment: Actually I don't have any real idea, I just tried to see if

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yeah, I understood the point with multiply by 4, I solved it, thanks. Do you have any idea for b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Try squaring numbers of the form 333....35. Can you find and prove a simple formula?

Comment: Oh i understood it, squaring 333....35 im getting 11122225 etc, thanks I think I solved it